# How to detect the insertion of a new data?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js, chart.js

I would like to know if there is a way to detect each time there is a new data inserted in a data table so that I can update a chart in my application.

I use postgreSQL, node.js, vue.js for the framework and chart js for the display.

Comment: You can have a trigger that runs `NOTIFY` and a daemon client process that is connected to the database and has run `LISTEN` so that it gets "woken up" by every `NOTIFY`. Look at the documentation for details. It is not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the source database table contains an `ID` column that is incremented by a `SEQUENCE`, you can repeatedly select new data as follows:

```
SELECT * from <table name> where ID > :lastSelectedID
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

In case the source table contains a column that holds the insertion date/time (i.e. `CREATED`), the same could look as follows:

```
SELECT * from <table name> where CREATED > :lastSelectedCreated
ORDER BY CREATED ASC;;
```